# php $_POST при сравнении со значением в переменной всегда выводит false

Tags: php, mysql

Вечер добрый, Уважаемые кодеры!

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в следующем..

Есть задача - сделать онлайн тест с вопросами и вариантами ответа, из которых только 1 верный, остальные - ложные.

Варианты ответов, которые в свою очередь хранятся в БД, выводятся в форме кнопок, соответственно, по нажатию на кнопку делается запрос на сравнение варианта ответа со значением из базы, после чего выдается сообщение об успехе или не успехе и выводится следующий вопрос

Решить эту задачу у меня получилось только при выводе лишь одного конкретного вопроса/записи из БД, но, если выводить вопросы/записи из БД в случайном порядке, нижеследующий код даже при правильном ответе говорит Пользователю, что тот ошибся

```
        $select=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table");
        $count=mysql_num_rows($select);
        $random=rand(1, $count);

        $select_random=mysql_query("SELECT ID
                                          ,QUESTION
                                          ,ANSWER_RIGHT -- Верный ответ, который сравнивается в фоне
                                          ,ANSWER_1 -- Верный ответ, который выводим с остальными вариантами
                                          ,ANSWER_2
                                          ,ANSWER_3
                                    FROM table
                                    WHERE ID = $random");
        $echo=mysql_fetch_assoc($select_random);

        /* тут должен быть кусочек кода по перемешиванию вариантов ответа, чтобы правильный ответ не
выводился всегда первым, но его тут нет, потому как суть вопроса в другом*/

        echo '<div>'.$echo['QUESTION'].'</div><p>
              <div>
                   <form method="post">
                         <input type="submit" name="name" value="'.$echo['ANSWER_1'].'"><p>
                         <input type="submit" name="name" value="'.$echo['ANSWER_2'].'"><p>
                         <input type="submit" name="name" value="'.$echo['ANSWER_3'].'">
                         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$echo['ID'].'">
                   </form>
              </div>';

        if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
                                    $id=$_POST['ID'];
                                    $select_query=mysql_query("SELECT ANSWER_RIGHT FROM table WHERE ID = $id");
                                    $echo_2=mysql_fetch_assoc($select_query);
                                    if ($_POST['name'] == $echo_2['ANSWER_RIGHT']) {echo 'Правильно';}
                                    else {echo 'Неправильно';}
                                   }
        else echo 'Выберите вариант ответа';
```

У меня есть предположение, что все дело в том, что при нажатии на кнопку начинает строится DOM, в котором сначала выбирается случайное значение уже для след. вопроса и сравнивается с пред. вопросом, в результате чего, какой бы вариант ответа Пользователь не выбрал, он всегда якобы будет не прав

Как это исправить, ума не приложу.. промучившись приличное время прошу совета у вас :)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А Вы уверены, что ответы одинаковые в БД? Напишите подробнее, что происходит при нажатии кнопки у Вас в проекте, почему формируется новый DOM

Comment: Да, ответы одинаковые, для проверки этого я спец. выводил то, что передается post'ом, что касается DOM.. поскольку в <form> не указывается action, при нажатии на кнопку приведенный мною код отрабатывает еще раз, т.е. показывается след. вопрос

Comment: Посмотрите, написал в ответе, удалю его потом.

Comment: в вашем коде сначала берется рандомное значения id, а потом вы пытаетесь сравнить пришедший ответ с id, которое конечно уже не то которое было в прошлой итерации. 

Например добавьте в форму id, вопроса и при отработки скрипта если вы получаете ответ - берите id из формы и забирайте из базы данных соответвующий, если э то не ответ - генерите форму вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том,  что из Бд сразу выбирается случайная запись и ответ с другого вопроса сравнивается с ответом этой записи. Перед этой строкой `if ($_POST['name'] == $echo['ANSWER_RIGHT'])` должен быть ещё один селект с выбором из БД записи по ID предыдущего вопроса. ID этого вопроса можно отправлять в поле `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'. $echo['ID']. '" />`

Comment: Json, Вы уловили ход моих мыслей про ответ на пред. вопрос, только я не очень понял как отправить ID пред. вопроса в input

Comment: ID отправит форма, если в неё дописать ещё одно поле `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'. $echo['ID']. '" />`, получить через `$_POST['id'] `

Comment: Json, да, я добавил ID в форму и добавил select в проверку:
`if (isset($_POST['name'])) { $id=$_POST['ID']; $select_query=mysql_query("SELECT ANSWER_RIGHT FROM table WHERE ID = $id"); $echo_2=mysql_fetch_assoc($select_query);
if ($_POST['name'] == $echo_2['ANSWER_RIGHT']) {echo 'Правильно';} else {echo 'Неправильно';} } else echo 'Выберите вариант ответа';`
но сравнение ответа идет опять с пред. вопросом

Comment: Возможно потому, что ID пустой, так как, если ничего не менялось, то запрос в переменной `$select_random=mysql_query("SELECT QUESTION
                                          ,ANSWER_RIGHT -- Верный ответ, который сравнивается в фоне
                                          ,ANSWER_1 -- Верный ответ, который выводим с остальными вариантами
                                          ,ANSWER_2
                                          ,ANSWER_3
                                    FROM table
                                    WHERE ID = $random");` не выбирает из БД поле ID.

Comment: ID там есть, я добавил

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос в шапке с тем кодом, который сейчас

Comment: Json, внес последние правки в код, что в описании вопроса

Comment: Json, я нашел ошибку - в моем коде, а именно здесь `$id=$_POST['ID'];` ID следует писать с маленькой буквы. Спасибо Вам ОГРОМНОЕ за подсказку!!

Answer (score 2):

Вот смотрите - это просто показать, ответ потом удалю:

```php
<?php
$echo['ANSWER_1'] = '1?';
$echo['ANSWER_2'] = '4?';
$echo['ANSWER_3'] = '5?';
$echo['ANSWER_RIGHT'] = $echo['ANSWER_2'];

echo '
<div>
<div>2+2 = ?</div><br>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="name" value="'.$echo['ANSWER_1'].'"><p>
            <input type="submit" name="name" value="'.$echo['ANSWER_2'].'"><p>
            <input type="submit" name="name" value="'.$echo['ANSWER_3'].'">
    </form>
</div>';
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    if ($_POST['name'] == $echo['ANSWER_RIGHT']) {
        echo 'Правильно';
    } else {
        echo 'Неправильно';
    }
}
```

В том случае, если данные совпадают, то всё работает корректно.

Comment: Ну да, я примерно так и проверял, когда подставлял опред. значения

Comment: @El Rey Вот попробуйте в коде у себя проверить просто совпадение. print_r($echo['ANSWER_RIGHT']); echo '<br>'; print_r($_POST['name']); и прям сравнить ещё раз. Может точка, может знак, может пробел.

Comment: а если вместо if ($_POST['name'] == $echo['ANSWER_RIGHT']) {
if (strcmp(trim($_POST['name']), trim($echo['ANSWER_RIGHT'])) === 0) {